# AWS Lambda Rest API: A sibling ({id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed Unable to create resource at path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm particular new to Lambda and to AWS in general. I'm trying to setup a simple REST  API Service with Lambda. I've used CloudFormat and CodePipeline to have a simple Express app. 
I'm trying to figure out why during the **deployment** phase, during **ExecuteChangeSet** I have this error:

`Errors found during import: Unable to create resource at path '/stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers': A sibling ({id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed Unable to create resource at path '/stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers/{userId}': A sibling ({id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed`

This is what I have inside the **template.yml**

```
      Events:
      AllowedUsers:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers
          Method: get
      AddAllowedUsers:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers
          Method: post    
      DeleteAllowedUsers:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers/{userId}
          Method: delete
      GetAllowedUser:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers/{userId}
          Method: get
```

I searched a bit for this error but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Are you deploying with cloudformation? I think it is a long standing bug on the AWS side

Comment: This appears to be an issue with AWS cloud formation. The work around appears to be delete the endpoint and add it back anew. Here's where people using Serverless have run into it and a workaround is discussed.d https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785

Comment: What's the cause of this error?

Comment: Something that worked for me is to write the same paths with the same path parameters and remove the stack and re deploy it. It's working now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me, the issue was different from what is described in the GitHub issue Bryan mentioned.

I was using **two different parameter names**. Finishing the refactoring and using a single id name fixed the issue.

Example:

```
DeleteAllowedUsers:
  Type: Api
    Properties:
      Path: /stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers/{id}
      Method: delete
GetAllowedUser:
  Type: Api
    Properties:
      Path: /stations/{stationId}/allowedUsers/{userId}
      Method: get
```

Answer (score 8):

You might encounter this issue when updating a variable path while using serverless ( and serverless.yaml ) to provision the AWS gatewayApi, here is a walk-around:

1. comment out the endpoint function to remove it completely
2. uncomment and deploy again

Comment: This worked. You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the walk around for this problem. It was posted on github by pettyalex.

link :https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).